# Sudden total meltdown: Cannot Find Symbol, ClassNotFoundException (Java, NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a java webapp (servlet), running in Tomcat; and a related external .jar library. Everything was fine, and suddenly, symbols (method names) can't be found. Even though I can run the app in netbeans, I can't build the app for deployment to the server: Build Failed; a series of Cannot Find Symbol errors related to an external .jar file, added as "library" in NetBeans. The library had been working fine and had not been changed:

.../src/java/com/shelterislandsoftware/alphascreen/screen/FeatureNumber.java:842:

```
   error: cannot find symbol
        this.formatType = SisFormat.valueOf(in.readUTF());
   symbol:   method valueOf(String)
   location: class SisFormat

.../src/java/com/shelterislandsoftware/alphascreen/screen/FeatureNumber.java:911:
   error: cannot find symbol
        out.writeUTF(formatType.name());
   symbol:   method name()
   location: variable formatType of type SisFormat
```

The source files of the `SisFormat.java` classes sit in the correct src folders they've always been in; the methods are present in the class and written correctly. Any suggestions? Thanks.

-- UPDATE: Now, I'm also unable to (re-)build an old JavaFx project. The java code has been built and working as an osx application; I wanted to change the icns image, and I can't rebuild. I doubt that the new image is the source of the build problem, just as I doubt that my (perfectly functional) java servlet code is the source of my build problem described above. I don't know for sure but I really suspect there's a problem with the new NetBeans 8.2 and / or osx Mojave. No one's interested, OK then. I've just copy-pasted the (formerly) library source classes directly into the main project described above, and this lets me build. It's suboptimal, as I'm using the same .jar file in a separate web app, so now I have two copies of the same classes to maintain. Oh, also, the same .jar that is unbuildable as an external jar now in this web app described above, is still perfectly buildable as an external jar in the other web app. Whatever.

Comment: Please don't be offended since my comments are meant constructively, but you need to rewrite your question: [1] It is too long. For example, delete the first two sentences. [2] It only has two paragraphs, and needs more. [3] Since you reinstalled NetBeans: [3a] Note the names of your _User directory_ and _Cache directory_ from the **Help > About** screen. [3b] Close NetBeans and delete them. [3c] Start NetBeans. It will recreate those directories that you deleted. [3d] Try again. [4] Post recent content of the NetBeans log (**View > IDE Log**) if you still have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, no offense taken, I'll work on that when I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. The new osx (Mojave) and the newest Netbeans as of writing (8.2) are intolerant of certain package names. I fixed the problem by altering my package names. Specifically, I had projects (in their own project directory) and a library (in its own library directory). While these directories were distinct in the computer's file system, the subsegment of those paths that Netbeans considers to be the "package name" had a common root element. Both the project(s) and the library "package name" started out like com.mydomain followed by the specific name of the project or library. I fixed the problem by changing the library package name to "lib.mydomain", and all the funky build problems ceased.